# Check OSX system

Tags: macos

Im development an app for OSX that will check the status of a MAC. I would like check:

- Memory in Hard Drive
- Memory Ram
- OS System...

Does anyone know how I can access these parameters?

Thanks for all!

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's already written that app.  It's called [System Information](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/04/06/mac-os-x-10-7-lion-features-new-system-information-app/).

There is a command-line version of the app, called [`system_profiler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html).  You can make it print out the information in XML for easy parsing.

The simplest way to get lots of information about the Mac programmatically is by running `system_profiler` as a child process and parsing its output.  You will want to look at using [`NSTask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I don't know what a “terminal sentence” is.

Comment: From xcode get de xml of system_profiler... Need i do an appleScript Project?

Comment: This isn't an Xcode problem. This is an Objective-C and Foundation framework problem. You need to be a programmer, you need to learn Objective-C, and you need to read the documentation I linked in my answer.